# An array of n alternating 1’s and -1’s in python

Tags: python

How would i go about creating an array that is a repetition of n 1's and -1's. 
i.e array[1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,...] for n times

I tried using numpy.repeat but it repeats each element rather than repeating 1 and -1 over and over.

edit: here is what i have tried:

```
import numpy as np

def repeat(n):
    z=np.arange(1,2)
    x=-np.arange(1,2)
    w=np.concatenate((x,z))
    return np.repeat(w,n)
```

which for n=3 returns

```
 array([-1, -1, -1,  1,  1,  1])
```

ideally, I would want this to be returning

```
 array([-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1])
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried?

Comment: You can't create an infinite list in Python. However, if you want to iterate over something for an undetermined length, you might want to look at [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)

Comment: @Kendas: The question seems to be describing a finite array (or maybe a list, if the questioner isn't aware of the difference).

Comment: I understand it as finite (for n times)

Answer (score 1):

```
alternating_list = [1,-1] * number_of_iterations
```

Comment: Very nice idea, but please avoid answering questions where the OP has demonstrated no effort in solving their own problem.

Comment: @ChristianDean - Normally I'd agree, but the op does mention *what* they tried...even if they havent shown it.

Comment: @Sayse Fair point. Although the OP should still _show_, what they've tried. only mentioning it isn't usually enough information. (Also, FYI: I didn't down-vote.)

Comment: In python there is usually a simple answer :) If you click the green tick next to the answer you accept it officially.